# How to make installable .exe file for unity games

Tags: unity, export, installer, build-process

I just completed my game but after i built the game from unity to *.exe* it also has `filename_data` folder i know it has all the resources for the game. I tried `iexpress` and `innosetup` to make the install-able file. I installed the game from the setup then i ran it but the game gives the error "There should be '`HouseFixIt_Data`' folder next to the executable", but i added data folder while making install-able file but still i'm getting this error. Please anyone help me...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[This](http://martin-klappacher.com/tutorial-windows-installer-for-your-unity-game/) is the online tutorial I used for InnoSetup, and I can confirm it worked for me.

At the part about the DataFolder they say this:

> Point the wizard to the main executable of your game. Now we have to
>   add the MyGame_Data folder. Click the Add folder. A quick note about
>   the MyGame_Data folder. You can select it directly, then click edit
>   and set the destination subfolder to “MyGame_Data”. This will create
>   the proper subdirectory once the installation is done and you will not
>   be including any unnecessary files.

**EDIT:**
As later asked by the OP in the comments, here is how to remove the Set Resolution Settings popup for a Unity game. Select Edit->PlayerSettings->Resolution and Presentation. Then select this option:
[image]

Comment: Really thank you very much. I have been struggling with this long time now its working fine. I was missed to change the destination subfolder. But still it showing configuration window is there any way to avoid this. That means i don't like to show that configuration window.

Comment: Are you talking about the Unity Configuration window, or some other configuration window?

Comment: Sorry for late response. Yes, the configuration window.

Comment: I might need a screen capture to fully understand your problem.

Comment: http://www.mediafire.com/view/r0e7t64i8abippu/win.png  This is the configuration window i'm talking about. I don't want to show this screen each time the player starts the game after installation.

Comment: @Albertkaruna Check my edited answer.

Comment: @ Ben BearFish Thanks Ben this is what i have been looking...

Comment: @BenBearFish can i use startup windows for my exe. so that it runs on startup?